# statistical test to compare two distributions with multiple measurements

Tags: statistical-test

I have two treatments: 15 patients have been assigned to treatment a and 14 to treatment b. For each patient, multiple measurements have been performed. For instance, 10 measurements for each patient. So for treatment a I have 10x15 samples, and for treatment b I have 10x14 samples. How can I test if there is an effect due to treatment (both mean value and dispersion)?

I was thinking of calculating the mean value and standard deviation for each patient, and then compare those values using the independent t test. Would that be correct?